# Example of filemaker script if statement, for someone to only see customers with UK field in table

Tags: filemaker

In filemaker security I only want users from a country such as Uk to see Uk customers in a table.

How would I write the if statement for this for example 
If(Country = “UK”; ????

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a field for country in your user table, you need to compare this for the logged in user to the country field in the table you want to restrict access to.

Such as:

> LoggedInUserCountry = Country

If this evaluates to true, the privilege is enabled.

LoggedInUserCountry should be a global field that is set during login, making it accessible from every table.

Comment: Where about's is this global field set? In privalidges?

Comment: A global field ia a regular field in a table set to global storage, ie. one value for all records. You set the calculation for determining if the user has access up for each table in privileges in the Manage Security panel.

Comment: What would be an example of the expression I would use to set the account to the global field?

Comment: The expression I gave in the answer should go into the privilege set calc. In the startup script you set the global field to the current user account using the Get(Accountname) function.

Comment: Can you give a example of a full expression

Comment: The expression is LoggedInUser = Get(AccountName).  First make a relationship from the table where you have the LoggedInUser field to the user account name in the Users table. Then use this relationship to get the current user’s country. Such as Sometable::LoggedInUserCountry = Users::Country. This is the best I can do without building it for you.